# Using Docker for Drupal Dev (Local)

Tags: drupal, nginx, docker, mariadb

So, to put it simply, I have a drupal site that's live.

I want to work on it locally and use docker containers to manage that.

I want to use this Image:
https://index.docker.io/u/bnchdrff/nginx-php5-drupal/

And use this as my data container:
https://index.docker.io/u/bnchdrff/mariadb/

I have the database downloaded from the live site saved as an .sql file.

I need to be able to use this pre-existing database.

Best case scenario is to be able to run the images in terminal and open a browser, navigate to something like 'localhost' and have the Drupal site pop up there for me to work on.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and have the latest version of Docker. Needless to say I have been working on trying to get this working for a while but don't want to complicate things with my failed attempts. Any and all suggestions welcomed.

Comment: So which part goes wrong exactly? No be able to load existing db? php5 container not be able to connect with db container? or not be able to access php5 container from browser?

Comment: Hi, I just want to know what commands to run once I have the two images mentioned above and the .sql file for example at /username/home/my-databases/sql-001.sql